# Cloudflare flexible ssl issue?

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, ssl, https, cloudflare

I spent my whole day configuring my wordpress website to use cloudflare flexible ssl.
I use WP HTTPS plugin and cloudflare page rule to redirect http to https.
It's working very well on firefox and IE but in chrome it's saying:

> The page at 'https://mrbladedesigns.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but is submitting data to an insecure location at 'http://mrbladedesigns.com/': this content should also be submitted over HTTPS.

One more thing I want to tell you guys that now also my wordpress address and Site address is **`HTTP`** in wordpress admin settings

I removed all of the insecure content but have no idea on how to resolve this.
**Any help will be appreciated!**

Answer (score 1):

Just disable W3 Total Cache, https cloudflare will working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I actually tried this as well but with more success. From your description it sounds like you have an issue with insecure content being loaded. This happens when you load the page via https but content is loaded via http.

The ssl insecure content fixer plugin will help you with most of your problems, but other problems will have to be fixed manually by changing http references in your html code to https.

Comment: What is the actual solution here?

Answer (score 0):

never mind I fixed it, SSL insecure didn't worked for me, the root cause of this problem was the **search bar** on my homepage. Here's the fix: under WP HTTPS settings at the end there's an option **Secure filters**. Just write **/?s** there and save it! Done!